# HP charger started to work a year later after Being burnt

Tags: hp

In December Last year, my hp charger got burnt while I was charging my laptop. The power adapter bulged and I had to keep it away in my old stuffs cause I didn't feel like throwing it away.11 months later while as I was going through my old stuff, I stumbled upon the power adapter and it was back to normal size. I was curious and wanted to know if it can work and surprisingly it did. Why?

Comment: Why? Because it always did. That it bulged only means overheating likely due to being used for something with  a power requirement that exceeded what the power supply could provide. In such circumstances it may bulge, work erratically or not at all temporarily. But CLEARLY it didn't burn.

Comment: That sometimes happens when it is not completely burnt. Some security circuits may have cut-in to stop the adapter from being completely destroyed. That could explain why it stopped working in December. Note that, if the excess current caused physical deformation, some components in the adapter will have taken a hit. Although it still might work, I would not call it a reliable adapter anymore.